# Connect to Kubernetes server from another server

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes

I have two instances one is Kubernetes server and other servers has installed Jenkins. admin.conf file of Kubernetes server transfered to jenkins server and then I tried to connect Kubernetes server from Jenkins server via Kubectl commands like  "kubectl --kubeconfig /data/admin.conf get namespaces"

I got follwoing error message

"Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "crypto/rsa: verification error" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "kubernetes")"

I also export admin.conf to KUBECONFIG

export KUBECONFIG=/data/admin.conf

But error as the same

Comment: Can you elaborate on your environment? If I understood correct by **Kubernetes server** you mean master node and another instance with Jenkins - this is a worker node of the same cluster? What does `kubectl cluster-info` say?

Comment: It is not a node of the cluster. I copied the admi.conf file from master node to jenkins server and tried with following command.
"kubectl --kubeconfig /data/admin.conf get namespaces"
My concern is is there a possibility to connect to master node from another instance which is not a part of the cluster.